# Nothing handled the event in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, dom-events

I am getting a basic feel for Ember, and running into some weird issues at the moment. The app is pretty basic (and ugly). On a specific route, (/stack) , I list out a bunch of cards that belong to this stack. `StackController` is an array controller since it retrieves a stack of cards that belong to it, essentially

```
StackController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

and

```
StackRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
         return App.Card.find();
    }
});
```

Then in my templates, I simply loop through it using the #each helper to display a property of the card ('front'), like this:

```
<ul>
{{#each}}
 <li>{{front}}</li> <button {{action 'backside' this}}>View</button>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Up until here, everything is working the way it should. However, when I click on the 'View' button to trigger the 'backside' event, it yields a :

**"Nothing handled the event 'backside'** " error. Kind of bummed because it seems pretty basic that it should do so, oh yes, I do explicitly specify the 'backside' event in my Controller, like this:

```
StackController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

   actions:{
      backside:function(){
           alert("backside event handled");
     }
    }
});
```

For a more detailed look, here is the jsBin:

http://jsbin.com/AHiTicU/5/edit

What am I doing wrong?

*The code in the JSBIN is accurate, there maybe some typos here however (unlikely, but a heads up).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `ember-1.0.0-rc.6`, in that version to use the action you need to put you action handler inside of the route, in a object with a key called `events`, like the following:

```
App.StackRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

        model: function(){     
                return App.Card.find();         // must substitute this with this.store.find('card'); 
        },
        events:{
                backside:function(){            
                        alert('working');               
                }
        }
});
```

Updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/AHiTicU/6/edit

I recommend you to use the lastest version, at the moment `1.2.0`, you can get it in the home page of emberjs website http://emberjs.com/.

So your current code will work http://jsbin.com/AHiTicU/9/edit